# Classes with disposable fields should be disposable

Tags: c#, fxcop

The FxCop warning "Classes with disposable fields should be disposable" sometimes confuses me. See contrived example below

Only one type *creates* and *owns* the disposable resource, but any number of types can *use* (or "borrow") this resource. I have seen developes take the FxCop warning on Util1 and Util2 to indicate that since they have a field of a disposable type, they must implement Dispose and dispose that field. That's clearly not what you want here.

Is the problem that

1. Making classes that only borrow disposable resources is an antipattern. The disposable resource could be passed as a method argument to Util1 and Util2, and the problem would go away. Only classes that *create* disposable resource should ever have them as fields, so that the field itself is what indicates ownership.
2. The warning isn't clever enough. It should be warning when types that *own*  disposable resources aren't themselves disposable, and in this scenario only one class owns it, while the others borrow it. The fact that it is injected only from a constructor parameter could have been used by a more clever rule to detect that the warning should not be raised for the borrowing class.
3. Something else?

```cs
static class Program
{
   public static void Main() 
   {
      using(var r = new SomeResource()) 
      {
          Console.WriteLine(new Util1(r).Foo());   
          Console.WriteLine(new Util2(r).Foo());   
      }                                 
   }
}

public sealed class SomeResource : IDisposable 
{
   private readonly NativeResource native;
   public void SomeResource() 
   {
      native = Native.CreateDisposableThing();
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
      native.Dispose();
   }
}

public sealed class Util1 {
   private readonly SomeResource res;
   public Util1(SomeResource res) {  this.res = res; }
   public string Foo() { /* uses res */ }
}

public sealed class Util2 {
   private readonly SomeResource res;
   public Util2(SomeResource res) {  this.res = res; }
   public string Foo() { /* uses res */ }
}
```

Comment: Well it is just static analysis, it can be right it can be wrong. It cannot know if you own or borow the resource, so if you know what you are doing - just disable this warning for this particular case. From the options you presented I'd say 2 is true.

Comment: I'd guess it's #2

Comment: I'm also fairly sure it's #2, but given how easy it seems to make the rule just at least ignore types where the IDisposable is *only* injected to a ctor, I was really curious if there was something more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most of case if you have a disposable field, it means you want to use it later and wrap it. If you return this field to external code, it can be disposed and break your own class unless you are able to check if resource was disposed before each usage.

If you just want to make a fabric, you don't need to keep the disposble resource as field.
That's why this rules is often true but in some special rare case you are able to make a "won't fix".

Other patterns are pretty rare because it is hard to maintain without introducing bug.

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of both 1 and 2. I suppose a good solution to the above case would be to either make the field a parameter in the Util (solution 1) *or* make these utilities private classes so they can't outlive the owner. The point about the borrower never being sure his resource is still alive is a good one - an argument for making the resource an argument to all the methods in the Util instead.

Comment: @AndersForsgren borrow pattern happens all the time and it not particulary rare. Take for example any asp.net application. Database connection (or Entity Framework context) is injected everywhere there, in constructor, but it's lifetime is managed externally and classes where it is injected are not responsible for disposing it.

Comment: Some patterns are considered acceptable if you trust your consumer, force it to respect a document or place a code analysis to complete them. Other case it is just a risk you want to take or not.